# Why does String() flatten an Array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I was surprised to discover flattening behavior of String constructor when applied to an Array.

Why does this work. And is this a good way to flatten an Array?

Tested to same results on Mac Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

```
String(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e', 'f']]])

=> "a,b,c,d,e,f"
```

Comment: It doesn't flatten, then the result would be `['a','b','c','d','e','f']` or the desired result `"abcdef"`

Comment: its not a good way to flatten an array. what if one of the strings included a comma?

Comment: Why not use array.flat when it's already supported in most of major browser

Comment: `alert(String(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e', {erm:'notsogood'}]]])); `Not a good way. Are you assuming all arrays are going to be characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because converting an array to a string will call `.toString` which is basically the same as calling `.join()`, which will call `.toString` onto all elements in the array, and then delemit the result with a comma. Therefore the arrays get recursively joined to a string, the result looks flattened as there is no indicator for the start or end of the array.
Here is the conversion step by step:

```
 [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]].toString()
 [1, 2, 3].toString() + "," + [1, 2, 3].toString()
 (1 + "," + 2 + "," + 3) + "," + (1 + "," + 2 + "," + 3)
 "1,2,3" + "1,2,3"
 "1,2,3,1,2,3"
```

Comment: This is correct. Array.prototye.toString() internally calls `Array.prototype.join()`. You can read about details [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5)

Answer (score 4):

It calls [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) - that is all.

Comment: The source you link to doesn't mention the recursive behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't flattern an array, it makes a string out of an array. 
For better options check out [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or, for example, some libraries like [lodash flattern()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatten) (or [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten) or [Rambda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten)).

Answer (score 1):

It is not the only way to convert an array into a string. Often `JSON.stringify` is preferred:

```js
const arr = [1,[2,[3]]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

The reason why it seems to 'flatten' the list is that it `String` is being called recursively on the whole array:

```js
const arr = [1,[2,[3]]];

console.log(
  String(arr)
);
console.log(
  String(arr[0]),
  '+ , +',
  String(arr[1])
);
console.log(
  String(arr[0]),
  '+ , +',
  String(arr[1][0]),
  '+ , +',
  String(arr[1][1])
);
```